# Print the current footprint of arbitrary objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to print out the current state of an object.

I want to only include variables that are declared using self (note: I do not want to see methods, or other information on the object). Currently I am using this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(', '.join("%s: %s" % (str(s), str(self.__dict__.get(s))) for s in self.__dict__))
```

In words:

- I loop over the object's `__dict__`
- For each value, I create a tuple that consists of the `str(key)` and `str(value)`
- The resulting tuple is joined in a string of the following format: `"key:value, key:value, ..."`

My question is, is there a more convenient way? Obviously, this uses the `__str__` method and I may want to change its behavior to serve another purpose.

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with printing `obj.__dict__` directly (or better yet, use `vars(obj)`? Using *representations* lets you debug issues far better than using string conversions.

Comment: How exactly do I use either for objects that lie out of the executing objects scope?

Comment: `repr(vars(self))` delegates worrying about other objects to those objects `__repr__` methods.

Comment: For your slightly snappy previous question, because the direct print of `__dict__` is a pain if you want to use it in CSV files. That is exactly wrong with printing them directly.

Comment: Then why not start your question from that point then instead? That'd be your actual problem to solve, a context for us to work with.

Comment: Although a pointless discussion: I was pretty clear on looking for another way that does not use `__str__`. Thank you for your input, I appreciate it, but please consider to not ask condescending questions while you help people.

Comment: I don't *mean* to be asking condescending questions. Can I ask in return that you keep an open mind and not read emotion in plain text comments?

Comment: Absolutely :) Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I was brought up in a [culture that expresses itself directly](http://stuffdutchpeoplelike.com/2011/05/28/dutch-directness/), which may differ from your expectations of how one states a question.

Comment: In that case, you should assume that people that are not brought up in the same culture will understand something that you did not intend. "So what exactly is wrong with X" implies any or all of the following: That I did it purposefully wrong in this way, that I should have known better, and that I acted against better judgement. None of these implications are helpful while looking for an answer to a problem. In any case, they discourage people from asking simple questions and are hazardous to academia in general.

Comment: Again, I do not wish to further a discussion on this or attack you, I am just sharing my experience in teaching. Always encourage people to ask questions and nourish interest :)